# How to dry this Ruby code (Active Admin/rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, dry

I feel I am repeating here too much the same and wish to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) it but I don't know how to.

I have a Prize model and one of the attribute is `prize_type` which is a select (you can choose one of the 4 values inside a CONSTANT called `PRIZE_TYPE`). I have a `table_for` for each type of prizes.

For example, I'd like to use some sort of mapping (`.map`?) in case one day, if I add a fifth or sixth value in the array `PRIZE_TYPE`, I want my panels to automatically add them without me having to copy/paste another `table_for` here below:

```
show do 

    def custom_number_to_currency(u)
      number_to_currency u,
        separator: ".",
        delimiter: ",",
        precision: 0,
        raise: true  
    end    



 panel "Details of Prizes" do

  table_for deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[0]) do |t|
    h3 "The deal has #{deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[0]).count} #{PRIZE_TYPES[0]}s
    initially set in the campaign for a total value of #{custom_number_to_currency (deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[0]).sum(:prize_unit_certified_market_value)) }", class: 'title-within-table'
    if deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[0]).count > 0 # if there is at least one record of 'jackpot prize'
      t.column("Prize")             { |prize| link_to( image_tag( prize.prize_image_url, class: 'main_img_in_admin_interface' ), admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank ) }
      t.column("Name")              { |prize| link_to prize.prize_name, admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank }
      t.column("Category")          { |prize| prize.prize_category }
      t.column("Initial quantity")  { |prize| prize.prize_initial_stock_quantity }
      t.column("Remaining quantity"){ |prize| if prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity == 0
                                                status_tag('no prizes left (all won)', :class => 'green')
                                              else
                                                prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity
                                              end } 

  end

  table_for deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[1]) do |t|
    h3 "The deal has #{deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[1]).count} #{PRIZE_TYPES[1]}s
    initially set in the campaign for a total value of #{custom_number_to_currency (deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[1]).sum(:prize_unit_certified_market_value)) }", class: 'title-within-table'
    if deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[1]).count > 0 # if there is at least one record of 'in-modal prize'
      t.column("Prize")             { |prize| link_to( image_tag( prize.prize_image_url, class: 'main_img_in_admin_interface' ), admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank ) }
      t.column("Name")              { |prize| link_to prize.prize_name, admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank }
      t.column("Category")          { |prize| prize.prize_category }
      t.column("Initial quantity")  { |prize| prize.prize_initial_stock_quantity }
      t.column("Remaining quantity"){ |prize| if prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity == 0
                                                status_tag('no prizes left (all won)', :class => 'green')
                                              else
                                                prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity
                                              end } 

  end

  table_for deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[2]) do |t|
    h3 "The deal has #{deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[2]).count} #{PRIZE_TYPES[2]}s
    initially set in the campaign for a total value of #{custom_number_to_currency (deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[2]).sum(:prize_unit_certified_market_value)) }", class: 'title-within-table'
    if deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[2]).count > 0 # if there is at least one record of 'Consolation prize'
      t.column("Prize")             { |prize| link_to( image_tag( prize.prize_image_url, class: 'main_img_in_admin_interface' ), admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank ) }
      t.column("Name")              { |prize| link_to prize.prize_name, admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank }
      t.column("Category")          { |prize| prize.prize_category }
      t.column("Initial quantity")  { |prize| prize.prize_initial_stock_quantity }
      t.column("Remaining quantity"){ |prize| if prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity == 0
                                                status_tag('no prizes left (all won)', :class => 'green')
                                              else
                                                prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity
                                              end } 

  end

  table_for deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[3]) do |t|
    h3 "The deal has #{deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[3]).count} #{PRIZE_TYPES[3]}s
    initially set in the campaign for a total value of #{custom_number_to_currency (deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[3]).sum(:prize_unit_certified_market_value)) }", class: 'title-within-table'
    if deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => PRIZE_TYPES[3]).count > 0 # if there is at least one record of 'Activation prize'
      t.column("Prize")             { |prize| link_to( image_tag( prize.prize_image_url, class: 'main_img_in_admin_interface' ), admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank ) }
      t.column("Name")              { |prize| link_to prize.prize_name, admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank }
      t.column("Category")          { |prize| prize.prize_category }
      t.column("Initial quantity")  { |prize| prize.prize_initial_stock_quantity }
      t.column("Remaining quantity"){ |prize| if prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity == 0
                                                status_tag('no prizes left (all won)', :class => 'green')
                                              else
                                                prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity
                                              end } 

  end
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code refactoring and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do this?

```
panel "Details of Prizes" do   
    PRIZE_TYPES.each do |prize_type|
      table_for deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => prize_type) do |t|
        h3 "The deal has #{deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => prize_type).count} #{prize_type}s
        initially set in the campaign for a total value of #{custom_number_to_currency (deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => prize_type).sum(:prize_unit_certified_market_value)) }", class: 'title-within-table'
        if deal.prizes.where(:prize_type => prize_type).count > 0 # if there is at least one record of 'jackpot prize'
          t.column("Prize")             { |prize| link_to( image_tag( prize.prize_image_url, class: 'main_img_in_admin_interface' ), admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank ) }
          t.column("Name")              { |prize| link_to prize.prize_name, admin_prize_path(prize), target: :blank }
          t.column("Category")          { |prize| prize.prize_category }
          t.column("Initial quantity")  { |prize| prize.prize_initial_stock_quantity }
          t.column("Remaining quantity"){ |prize| if prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity == 0
                                                    status_tag('no prizes left (all won)', :class => 'green')
                                                  else
                                                    prize.prize_remaining_stock_quantity
                                                  end }  
   end
end
```